# Problem to extend a Singularity image from an existing docker image

Tags: python, docker, singularity-container

I try to extend the [pytorch docker image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/pytorch/pytorch/1.4-cuda10.1-cudnn7-runtime/images/sha256-ee783a4c0fccc7317c150450e84579544e171dd01a3f76cf2711262aced85bf7?context=explore) with my definition file `nnunet.def`:

```
Bootstrap: docker
From: pytorch/pytorch:1.4-cuda10.1-cudnn7-runtime

%post
    git clone https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex
    cd apex
    pip install -v --no-cache-dir ./

%runscript
    echo "Running nnunet container..."
```

However, when I build this image (with `sudo singularity build image.sif nnunet.def`) I get the an error saying pip is not found:

```
...
+ pip install -v --no-cache-dir ./
/.build-script-post: 6: /.build-script-post: pip: not found
FATAL:   failed to execute %post proc: exit status 127
FATAL:   While performing build: while running engine: while running /usr/local/libexec/singularity/bin/starter: exit status 255
```

Why?

What is even more surprising is that when I enter in a shell directly from this image:
`singularity shell docker://pytorch/pytorch:1.4-cuda10.1-cudnn7-runtime`

I have no problem using pip:

```
Singularity> pip freeze
asn1crypto==1.2.0
backcall==0.1.0
...
```

Why can't I use pip in the `%post` section of my definition file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: the value of `$PATH` in `%post` is different from when you're running in shell, so it doesn't know where to look.

If you look at where pip is located (`which pip`) in either the docker or singularity image, it is at `/opt/conda/bin/pip`. The default path used in `%post` is `/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin`.

When you see an error stating that a command is not available when run as part of a script but it is when you run interactively, it is almost always an environmental issue and `PATH`, `PYTHONPATH`, `PERL5LIB`, etc. are the frequent culprits.

If you add `export PATH=/opt/conda/bin:$PATH` to the beginning of the `%post` block it should solve this issue.